# “De quoi” ou “ce dont” dans divers contextes

Tags: locutions, pronoms-relatifs

J’ai vu les locutions suivantes :

- Je sais ce dont j’ai besoin
- Je sais de quoi il est question
- Tu ne sais pas de quoi je suis capable

Je me demande si on peut utiliser l’un ou l’autre, ou s’il s’agit de contextes spécifiques. Ma pensée est que “ce dont” s’utilise quand “de” fait partie d’un verbe (avoir besoin de), tandis que “de quoi” s’utilise quand “de” n’en fait pas partie.

Ils semblent tous deux vouloir dire la même chose, donc je veux savoir comment utiliser chacun.

Comment: Oui, les deux sont interchangeables, personne ne te le reprochera (ou même s'en apercevra). Pour la/les différences entre ces deux mots en revanche, je ne peux pas t'aider, désolé ! Si je devais, je dirais que "de quoi" est plus familier que "ce dont", mais encore même ça je ne suis pas sûr !

Comment: A mon avis ce qui rend "de quoi" plus familier est son emploi à la place de "ce dont". Comme "je sais de quoi j'ai besoin". Et c'est peut-être aussi dû à son utilisation plus fréquente (et même plus qu'elle ne le devrait), ce qui est alors une question d'impression, "à l'oreille".

Comment: @Maryannah Merci beaucoup ! Pourvu qu’ils soient interchangeables, je n’y réfléchirai pas à deux fois. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C'est effectivement une bonne intuition. Dans le cas d'un COI ou d'un complément de nom, on utilisera "dont". Dans les autres cas on utilisera alors "que"/"quoi".

> Les personnes dont je suis responsable *(de qui ? = COI)*
>
> Je vous ai dit tout ce que je sais *(quoi ? = COD)*
>
> Ce dont je suis sûr *(de quoi ? = COI)*, c'est qu'il nous ment !

A noter que "ce à quoi" s'emploie comme "ce dont".

> Quand tu me l'as dit, c'est ce à quoi je pensais.

Tous ces éléments sont appelés **pronoms relatifs neutres**.

Comment: Ma réponse est en accord avec le thème du site, autour des *finest points* de la langue.. en pratique en effet, à l'oral, on peut s'autoriser plus de souplesse. Mais c'est toujours mieux de connaître la règle ;)

Comment: Oh! Tu me l’as expliqué très bien. Je sais que “ce” s’ajoute quand il n’existe aucun antécédent. Ces règles m’ont pris un bon moment à maîtriser, mais je pense que me débrouiller assez bien. :)

Comment: Ahah, avec plaisir ;) "les maîtriser" et "je pense ø me débrouiller" et c'est parfait !

Comment: Pardon mais je ne comprends pas “ø” à moins que tu ne veuilles dire à omettre “que”?

Comment: Oui c'est ça, ø est l'ensemble vide. https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_vide

Comment: Ah je ne savais pas qu’une telle chose existait. :)

Comment: Merci la culture scientifique pour ma part haha (et le Bac Scientifique accessoirement)

Answer (score -1):

C'est une question très difficile et il n'est pas possible de la traiter en quelques lignes. J'espère ne pas m'être trompé et de ne causer à personne une longue lecture inutile, mais quoi qu'il en soit, le texte renferme pour la personne intéressée des informations partielles indéniables.

Les deux sont utilisables pour exprimer la même chose **dans certains cas seulement**, mais « ce dont » n'est [pas autant utilisé](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=je+sais+de+quoi%2Cje+sais+ce+dont&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cje%20sais%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cje%20sais%20ce%20dont%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cje%20sais%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cje%20sais%20ce%20dont%3B%2Cc0) pour les verbes courant et est uniquement utilisé pour des verbes plus rares d'emploi (on pourra se convaincre de cela à la vérification des ngrams à la fin du développement), et dans la langue parlée seulement les personnes instruites utilisent  « ce dont ».

Les cas lorsque c'est possible sont ceux où la préposition « de »  est la préposition que l'on utilise normalement avec le verbe de la subordonnée ; de plus le verbe de la principale ne peut pas être n'importe quel verbe ; s'il est intransitif est qu'il est construit avec « de » la correspondance n'existe pas. Si la préposition est différente il n'y a pas de correspondance.

Il existe plusieurs schémas d'utilisation pour lesquels, en fait, il n'est pas du tout question d'interchangeabilité des deux formes.

**I** Il y a d'abord le cas de locutions figées dans lesquelles on considère « quoi » comme étant un pronom relatif ;

- Avoir de quoi faire bouillir la marmite
- Il n'y a pas de quoi fouetter un chat
- Il y a de quoi s'y confondre. (s'y perdre, y perdre son latin, en perdre la tête, …) (*shéma de locutions*)
- Avoir de quoi faire.
- Il n'y a pas de quoi être fier. (rire, s'étonner, pleurer, …)
- En foi de quoi (formule utilisée au bas de certains actes administratifs)
- Avoir de quoi frire. (vivre, se nourrir, …)
- Il y a de quoi se pendre (se taper la tête contre les murs, tout plaquer là et …, …)
- Pour raison de quoi
- Il n'y a pas de quoi rire.
- Il n'y a pas de quoi se vanter.

Dans aucun de ces cas de locution y a-t-il la possibilité de remplacement équivalent ;  de plus, il n'est nullement question de construction du verbe avec « de » ; on ne dit pas du tout  « frire de », « faire de », « pleurer de  » ; si on dit « se vanter de », « rire de », la construction  utilisé ci-dessus n'est pas celle-ci. Selon mon point de vue, « De quoi » s'analyse comme étant une locution signifiant « matière à , le(s) moyen(s) permettant de » dans laquelle le pronom relatif perd sa valeur de pronom.
Les constatations suivantes dans LBU tendent à confirmer cela ;

- « Quoi » s'emploie sans antécédent dans la formule « de quoi » suivie d'un infinitif;
  *exemple* Voulez-vous DE QUOI racheter une petite voiture ?

Il existe une locution idiomatique dans laquelle est manifeste une pseudo-relation pronominale en raison que « Il retourne de … » ne se dit pas ;

- Comprendre, savoir de quoi il retourne —  Comprendre, savoir ce dont il retourne.

**II** Il y a ensuite une locution figée où « de quoi » termine une phrase ; en ce qui concerne celles-là aussi il n'y a pas de remplacement possible par « ce dont » ;

- Avoir de quoi. (avoir des moyens financiers, de l'argent)

**III**

On peut arriver à une compréhension plus exacte de la locution « de quoi » en considérant l'évolution historique ;

À partir de la source « [études littéraires](https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic30348-ce-a-quoi-et-ce-de-quoi.html) » on s'aperçoit que « de quoi », en particulier dans les phrases de type « Je sais de quoi … » peut n'être qu'une anomalie.

> « ce de quoi » est possible, non redondant, mais certainement désuet :

C'est tout **ce de quoi** j'ai besoin, Malherbe, poème
Et tel blâme en autrui **ce de quoi** je l'estime , Régnier , Satires
Où pourrai-je trouver de quoi te faire un don Qui puisse tenir lieu d'une reconnaissance ? Je l'ai, mon Dieu, j'ai **ce de quoi** Te faire une agréable offrande, Corneille , L'imitation de Jésus-Christ.

On voit  que « de quoi »  et « ce de quoi » sont utilisés dans les deux dernières phrases de Corneille et de plus que la première de ces utilisations  correspond à celle de la locution qui se dégage ci-dessus, locution dans laquelle la valeur de pronom est perdue ; s'agirait-il de  « faire un don **de** qc à qu » ? Il faudrait comprendre alors que s'impose la nécessité de chercher un endroit où sera révélé quelle chose qui est convenable pour faire l'objet d'un don ; cela est clairement hors de question en tant que signification, c'est trop compliqué et n'est pas justifiable, et donc il s'agit bien de la locution nominale conçue ci-dessus (Où pourrais-je trouver *les moyens permettant de* te faire un don Qui puisse …). Pour ce qui est de la seconde, il faut comprendre que « l' » a comme antécédent « de quoi » (première occurrence) c'est à dire le moyen et que ce moyen est matérialisé en quelque chose dont la personne qui parle est en possession (ce) ; on voit qu'il ne s'agit pas d'un moyen mais bien de quelque chose puisqu'il s'agit du [don de la personne](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ZG8_AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA450&lpg=PA450&dq=O%C3%B9+pourrai-je+trouver+de+quoi+te+faire+un+don&source=bl&ots=uJbtJYsQL9&sig=ACfU3U075oaFUfNIs5neHLq_D2Xe84_LqQ&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZpqOI9tHiAhVOXBoKHYcNDssQ6AEwAnoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=O%C3%B9%20pourrai-je%20trouver%20de%20quoi%20te%20faire%20un%20don&f=false) ; on est  donc en présence du pronom relatif avec sa fonction pleine (ce qui semble être le cas dans toutes ces combinaisons de « ce » avec « de quoi ».

On peut voir maintenant qu'en la forme « de quoi » l'on n'est pas confronté à une unique locution mais à deux, celle qui nous vient non adultérée du français traditionnel et une qui est une locution nominale (matière à) et celle qui nous vient d'un français plus récent et qui résulte d'une atrophie de la locution « ce de quoi » en « de quoi » en raison nous dirons certains, de sa lourdeur (qui est loin d'être aussi lourde qu'un « qu'est-ce que c'est  » dans « Qu'est-ce que c'est cette chose sur la table ? »). Quoi qu'il en soit de la raison c'est la locution que l'on trouve dans les deux dernières phrases proposées dans le problème ;

- Je sais de quoi il est question. *« Il est question de **quoi** », « quoi » étant  « la chose »  que je sais. Seulement cette chose n'est pas signifiée : on ne lit pas «  Je sais la chose  il est question de quoi. » ou en d'autre termes «  Je sais **ce** de quoi il est question. » mais «  Je sais de quoi il est question. »*
- Tu ne sais pas de quoi je suis capable.  *même explication que pour la phrase précédente*

On peut supposer que la coexistence des deux locutions (« de quoi » et « ce de quoi ») est la cause de la désuétude de la seconde qui a été amalgamée à la première et que la cause de cette désuétude n'est pas une supposée lourdeur ; ce qui porte à croire cela c'est qu'il n'y a aucun problème de désuétude en ce qui concerne les locutions de fonction et de « lourdeur » très voisines que sont « ce à quoi », « ce en quoi », « ce pour quoi », « ce sur quoi ».

exemples tirés du LBU

- La passion fanatique de gens, qui défendaient CE à quoi ils
  avaient donné leur vie (MALRAUX, Noyers de l'Altenburg, p . 8
- Soyez le contraire de CE À QUOI l'on s'attend. (STENDHAL, Rouge, II, 24)
- Pour CE À QUOI vous êtes bon [= utile], vous pouvez bien vous promener. (BALZAC,
  Goriot, p. 219)
- Certains de ces noms montrent que la langue écrite […] aura une place accrue, ce à quoi contribuent aussi un musicien comme Berlioz, un
  peintre comme Cézanne, […], etc. (avant-propos du LBU, 12<sup>e</sup> ed.)
- Les deux gestes qui sont à l'origine de ce livre [...]
  ne pourraient plus être tracés aujourd'hui de la même façon (CE pour quoi je renonce
  à le corriger). (BARTHES, Mytkologies, p. 7)
- Ceux qui ne savent pas croient que les biens désignent uniquement les objets matériels [...], CE en quoi ils se trompent lourdement. (PILHES, Imprécateur, p. 14)

exemples tirés de Linguee

- Nous avons besoin de votre feed-back pour mieux vous comprendre et c'est ce sur quoi nous travaillons en ce moment. 
  -[...]   possible en produisant ce qu'il y a de mieux, et ce sur quoi nous travaillons est la recherche  de véritables excédents et non de pseudo-excédents.
- Je ne peux vous dire combien je suis ravie que vous ayez posé la question car c'est exactement ce sur quoi nous travaillons.
- Voilà ce sur quoi nous travaillons actuellement.

**IV** On comprend maintenant mieux le remplacement possible de « de quoi » par « ce dont » : on remplace en fait « ce de quoi » par « ce dont » dans une locution où « ce » manque, ou, selon une autre optique on remplace « de quoi » par « dont », cela correspondant à la logique des pronoms « quoi » et « dont ». On voit ensuite que cette logique explique en partie le fait que le remplacement envisagé n'a qu'une portée  limitée ; en plus des cas concernant la locution nominale – on ne trouve ci-dessus qu'un remplacement possible (dans un idiomatisme pas tout à fait logique) : savoir de quoi il retourne – on trouve de nombreux cas ;

- Je parle **de ce dont** je m'occupe en ce moment.    <s>de de quoi</s>, *« [de ce de quoi](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=de+ce++de+quoi&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cde%20ce%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cde%20ce%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0) » est correct, ce qui montre que la substitution normale et non celle envisagé est la seule utile lorsque l'atrophie est éliminée.*
- Je parle **de quoi** je travaille en ce moment.      <s>ce dont</s>, *Par la substitution on passe de « parler **de** quelque chose » à « parler quelque chose », un autre verbe, ce qui ne peut pas aller.*

(*même schéma que l'exemple précédent)*

- Je discute **de ce dont** vous parliez hier.
- Je discute **de quoi** vous avez perdu à la bourse.

- Ils s'entrainent **à ce dont** vous n'auriez pas l'idée de penser.   <s>à de quoi</s>,  *[à ce de quoi](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A0+ce+de+quoi&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%A0%20ce%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C%C3%A0%20ce%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0) est correct, « à de quoi » ne l'est pas, ce qui montre que la substitution logique pour « de quoi » n'est que « dont » et vice versa.*
- Ils s'entrainent  **à quoi** vous n'auriez pas l'idée de penser.

Ils s'ensuit que lorsque « de » fait partie du verbe de la principale la substitution n'a pas de sens ; la règle est qu'il est nécessaire que « quoi »soit un pronom relatif véritable (élimination des conjonctions nominales) et que « de » fasse partie du verbe de la subordonnée ou de façon équivalente que « quoi » soit un pronom relatif complément d'objet indirect. Lorsque cette condition est remplie on est assuré de la substitution dans le sens « de quoi → ce dont » ; c'est à dire que si l'on trouve la forme « de quoi » et qu'elle remplie les conditions, alors la substitution est sans problème. La raison qu'il n'est pas possible de faire cela dans l'autre sens est une question d'usage : l'atrophie est devenue naturelle pour quelques verbes courants comme « savoir » seulement ;

- voir, savoir, demander, sentir, expliquer, connaitre, examiner, raconter, rappeler, prendre, comprendre, penser, …  ([voir](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=voir+de+quoi+*%2Cvoir+ce+dont+*%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cvoir%20de%20quoi%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bvoir%20de%20quoi%20il%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvoir%20de%20quoi%20elle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvoir%20de%20quoi%20se%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvoir%20de%20quoi%20est%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvoir%20de%20quoi%20ils%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvoir%20de%20quoi%20je%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvoir%20de%20quoi%20l%27%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvoir%20de%20quoi%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvoir%20de%20quoi%20vous%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvoir%20de%20quoi%20sont%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cvoir%20ce%20dont%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bvoir%20ce%20dont%20il%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvoir%20ce%20dont%20est%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvoir%20ce%20dont%20ils%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvoir%20ce%20dont%20elle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvoir%20ce%20dont%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvoir%20ce%20dont%20nous%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvoir%20ce%20dont%20je%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvoir%20ce%20dont%20le%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvoir%20ce%20dont%20elles%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvoir%20ce%20dont%20la%3B%2Cc0),
  [savoir](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=savoir+de+quoi+*%2Csavoir+ce+dont+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Csavoir%20de%20quoi%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsavoir%20de%20quoi%20il%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsavoir%20de%20quoi%20l%27%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsavoir%20de%20quoi%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsavoir%20de%20quoi%20ils%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsavoir%20de%20quoi%20elle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsavoir%20de%20quoi%20se%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsavoir%20de%20quoi%20je%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsavoir%20de%20quoi%20nous%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsavoir%20de%20quoi%20est%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsavoir%20de%20quoi%20demain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Csavoir%20ce%20dont%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsavoir%20ce%20dont%20il%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsavoir%20ce%20dont%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsavoir%20ce%20dont%20ils%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsavoir%20ce%20dont%20elle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsavoir%20ce%20dont%20nous%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsavoir%20ce%20dont%20l%27%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsavoir%20ce%20dont%20je%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsavoir%20ce%20dont%20les%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsavoir%20ce%20dont%20le%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsavoir%20ce%20dont%20tu%3B%2Cc0),
  [demander](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*+demande+de+quoi%2C*+demande+de+quoi%2C*+demande+ce+dont%2C*+demande+ce+dont&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20demande%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bse%20demande%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bme%20demande%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blui%20demande%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvous%20demande%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20demande%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bet%20demande%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bje%20demande%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bleur%20demande%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnous%20demande%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20demande%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C%2A%20demande%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bse%20demande%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bme%20demande%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blui%20demande%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvous%20demande%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20demande%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bet%20demande%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bje%20demande%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bleur%20demande%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnous%20demande%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bil%20demande%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C%2A%20demande%20ce%20dont%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Blui%20demande%20ce%20dont%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bleur%20demande%20ce%20dont%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C%2A%20demande%20ce%20dont%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Blui%20demande%20ce%20dont%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bleur%20demande%20ce%20dont%3B%2Cc0), 
  [sentir](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sentir+de+quoi+*%2Csentir+ce+dont+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csentir%20de%20quoi%20il%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csentir%20ce%20dont%20il%3B%2Cc0),
  [expliquer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=expliquer+de+quoi+*%2Cexpliquer+ce+dont+il+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexpliquer%20de%20quoi%20il%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cexpliquer%20ce%20dont%20il%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bexpliquer%20ce%20dont%20il%20s%27agit%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bexpliquer%20ce%20dont%20il%20s%27agissait%3B%2Cc0), 
  [connaitre](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=conna%C3%AEtre+de+quoi+*%2Cconna%C3%AEtre+ce+dont+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cconna%C3%AEtre%20de%20quoi%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bconna%C3%AEtre%20de%20quoi%20se%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bconna%C3%AEtre%20de%20quoi%20il%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bconna%C3%AEtre%20de%20quoi%20elle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cconna%C3%AEtre%20ce%20dont%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bconna%C3%AEtre%20ce%20dont%20il%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bconna%C3%AEtre%20ce%20dont%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bconna%C3%AEtre%20ce%20dont%20ils%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bconna%C3%AEtre%20ce%20dont%20nous%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bconna%C3%AEtre%20ce%20dont%20elle%3B%2Cc0), 
  [examiner](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=examiner+de+quoi+*%2Cexaminer+ce+dont+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cexaminer%20de%20quoi%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bexaminer%20de%20quoi%20se%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bexaminer%20de%20quoi%20il%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexaminer%20ce%20dont%20il%3B%2Cc0), 
  [raconter](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=raconter+de+quoi%2Craconter+ce+dont&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Craconter%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Craconter%20ce%20dont%3B%2Cc0), 
  [rappeler](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rappeler+de+quoi%2Crappeler+ce+dont&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crappeler%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crappeler%20ce%20dont%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Crappeler%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crappeler%20ce%20dont%3B%2Cc0), 
  [prendre](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prendre+de+quoi%2Cprendre+ce+dont&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprendre%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprendre%20ce%20dont%3B%2Cc0),
  [comprendre](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comprendre+de+quoi+*%2Ccomprendre+ce+dont&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Ccomprendre%20de%20quoi%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcomprendre%20de%20quoi%20il%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomprendre%20de%20quoi%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomprendre%20de%20quoi%20est%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomprendre%20de%20quoi%20je%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomprendre%20de%20quoi%20elle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomprendre%20de%20quoi%20l%27%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomprendre%20de%20quoi%20ils%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomprendre%20de%20quoi%20se%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomprendre%20de%20quoi%20%C3%A9tait%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomprendre%20de%20quoi%20le%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomprendre%20ce%20dont%3B%2Cc0),
  [penser](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=penser+de+quoi%2Cpenser+ce+dont&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpenser%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpenser%20ce%20dont%3B%2Cc0)
  )

Pour des verbes autres que ceux-là, l'usage est de n'utiliser que « ce dont » ;

- utiliser, pratiquer, apprécier, refuser, … ([utiliser](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=utiliser+de+quoi%2Cutiliser+ce+dont&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cutiliser%20ce%20dont%3B%2Cc0),[pratiquer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pratiquer+de+quoi%2Cpratiquer+ce+dont&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpratiquer%20ce%20dont%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpratiquer%20ce%20dont%3B%2Cc0), [apprécier](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=appr%C3%A9cier+de+quoi%2Cappr%C3%A9cier+ce+dont&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cappr%C3%A9cier%20ce%20dont%3B%2Cc0), [refuser](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=refuser+de+quoi%2Crefuser+ce+dont&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crefuser%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crefuser%20ce%20dont%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Crefuser%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crefuser%20ce%20dont%3B%2Cc0)¹)

¹<sub>La courbe pour « refuser de quoi » est un faux positif : il ne s'agit que de la locution nominale.</sub>

Comment: Ça m’a pris un moment de traiter vraiment et comprendre tout ce que tu as écrit, et il y en a beaucoup à prendre en compte. Je dois tout relire toujours et encore pour l’intérioriser, mais j’apprécie que tu avais pris du temps d’expliquer et d’écrire une telle réponse approfondie.

Comment: @tssmith2425 I hope this insight I provide into the problem is convincing, that it makes things clear; however, if it fails to make sense, do not worry about giving it no credit : I enjoyed the research process very much and so I spent my time well. I know its rather specialised knowledge and one must be very curious to want to know about such things. Nevertheless, let only the full assurance of seeing something right in it guide the use you'll make of it.